# VBA Copy & Paste is pasting some values in incorrect row while some are correct

Tags: excel, vba, copy-paste

I'm having an issue with copying and pasting values in VBA where most row values are being pasted in the correct row. However, after a certain column it pastes the row values 6 rows down. It seems like it's adding an offset somewhere in the loop but I cannot figure out where. I've tried different variations of the PasteSpecial function with the same result. Below is the code that copies and pastes:

```
s1.Activate
    'Assumes max 10 shipments per distributor
    With s1
        Totrows = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row - 1
    End With
    'Range(Cells(3, 1), Cells(3, 1).End(xlDown).Address).Rows.Count 2
    'Loop through rows to see if we want them
     For i = 4 To Totrows Step 3
         If Cells(i, 1) = 1 Then
         Range("A"&CStr(i),"CW"&CStr(i)).Copy 'Destination:=s2.Rows(j)
         'activates All Geo Zones worksheet

         s2.Activate
         Rows(j).Select
         'Range("A"&j).End(xlUp).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
         'Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
         Range("A"&Cstr(j),"CW"&CStr(j)).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
         'Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
            'Create unique id
            If Cells(j, 2) = Cells(j - 1, 2) And Cells(j, 3) = Cells(j - 1, 3) And Cells(j, 5) = Cells(j - 1, 5) Then
                Cells(j, 1) = Cells(j, 1) + 1
            End If


         s1.Activate
         'Copy row and paste it to the other worksheet
         j = j + 1
         End If

     Next i
```

You can see I'm selecting a range from columns A to CW in the s1 sheet, and then activating s2 and pasting the values into the same range in row j (starts at 3). The If statement below that checks if it's a duplicate order and changes the ID. I don't think this has any effect on the pasting. 
I've attached a screenshot of the results. You can see where I've outlined the values that are supposed to be in the first row, but are now in row 7. I don't understand why most of the values are pasted correctly, but these are being pasted a few rows down. The last column in this image is CW, just as a note. [image]

Comment: Side note: the `CStr` are redundant, `Range("A" & i` is fine.

Comment: Ah, gotcha. This comes from my Python background where I have to convert integers to strings if I want to concatenate them haha.

Comment: `&` forces string concatenation... see the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/ampersand-operator).